# Undead Anatomy 4 question

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e

I was working on something with the [Undead Anatomy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/u/undead-anatomy-i/) spell and the 4th version has me a little confused. It lists some ability score changes listed as size for tiny and large undead, but those sizes are already covered under UA2. I believe these modifiers are only supposed to be for incorporeal forms, but does not specifically say so. But then why isnt there new ones for small and medium?

So if you used UA4 to change into a corporeal tiny/large undead, would you use the modifiers listed under UA2 or UA4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Undead Anatomy 4 overrules its earlier counterpart

[Undead Anatomy](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Undead%20Anatomy%20IV) 4 provides better ability score adjustments than UA2; and specifies in its details

> This spell functions as undead anatomy III, except it allows you to use more abilities. [...]

> Tiny undead: **If the form you take is that of a Tiny undead**, you gain a –2 penalty to your Strength, a +8 size bonus to your Dexterity, and a +3 natural armor bonus.
> Large undead: **If the form you take is that of a Large undead**, you gain a +6 size bonus to your Strength, a –2 penalty on your Dexterity, a +2 size bonus to your Constitution, and a +6 natural armor bonus.

There are no caveats to the ability modifications, nor allowance to use the versions from UA2; this spell says you get these modifications (which are almost all direct improvements from UA2) so you do.

Comment: I wasnt thinking this was the route because this is the only spell that changes the ability score and natural armor modifiers out of the poly spells.